# How to link content and its localized version in strapi?

Tags: strapi

I'm discovering strapi (v4.20.0) and I encounter some issues with localized versions of my contents.

I created a collection and made it translatable. I then filled my content in the default locale and published it before starting internationalization by setting the local drop down to the secondary locale and clicking *Fill in from another locale*.

After saving, I can find both my default locale content and my localized content in the collection list, however they do not seems to be linked. If I edit the default content and switch locale, I get a blank page with as if it was the first time. Moreover if I investigate my database, the table *my_collection_localizations_links* is still empty.

Am I missing something ? Is there a specific handling to link two contents as one being the localized version of the other ?

Answer (score 0):

I just did a quick video on the workflow to use;
https://www.loom.com/share/f0bc8a0754314d93a47fbbc277f1545c?sid=6685bd28-b46b-4dc4-9e2c-a6b23682d2cc

I think that I used the same steps as you.
Please let me know if I missed something.

Lake sure to start by selecting the local you want to edit, and then click on the Fill from another local.

Have a great day.

Comment: Thank for your answer however my problem is not that I cannot create a localized version of a content, filling from another locale is working, but that my newly created content is not linked by any way at the "main" content. If I go back to the page an switch locale again I end up on a blank page and not on the localized version of it. Moreover if I query my page on the api with populate=* my localizations is empty.

Comment: Hello, 
Thanks a lot for the precision.
Is that related to this GitHub issue here: https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/19486
If it's the case, we are on it 

Comment: That exactly the issue I'm facing, thank you :)

Comment: Hello, it's fixed in the 4.20.1 that we released yesterday.
Sorry again for that issue.